# How to merge same columns from two different DataFrames

Tags: pandas

I have two Dataframes A and B. Both have same 4 columns. I want to merge the two data frames such that if first three column values match, then merge the id values(which is a jasonb array)

## Sample data:

### df_A

```
name     age    zip      id
abc      25     11111    ["2722", "2855", "3583"]
```

### df_B

```
name     age    zip      id
abc      25     11111    ["123", "234"]
```

I want the final output to look like

### Final output:

```
name     age    zip      id
----------------------------------------------------------------
abc      25     11111    ["2722", "2855", "3583", "123", "234"]
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution will be

```
l=['name','age','zip']
df=(df1.set_index(l)+df2.set_index(l)).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to `merge`, then use a list comprehension to handle the "id" columns.

```
output = df_A.merge(df_B, on=['name', 'age', 'zip'])
output['id'] = [[*x, *y] for x, y in zip(output.pop('id_x'), output.pop('id_y'))] 

output
  name  age    zip                            id
0  abc   25  11111  [2722, 2855, 3583, 123, 234]
```